# Lighting Estimation Algorithms Used in ARCore

Tags: arcore

Does anyone know what are the [lighting estimation](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/lighting-estimation?hl=en) algorithms used in ARCore?
And where can I find the source code if exists?

Thanks in advance.